# how to reverse the integers between two strings with changing lower to upper & upper to case alphabets in c

Tags: c, string, reverse

I have an input string such as :`"Hello 12345 WoRlD"`
and I want output it as : `"hELLO 54321 wOrLd"`

1)here the lower case should be converted to upper and vice versa

2)reverse the integers between two strings

after executing it will only prints first string only and the rest of output vanishes

Here is what I have attempted so far

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char* casechange(char *);
main()
{
    char s[30],*p,*q;
    int i,j;
    printf("Enter string data:");
    scanf("%s",s);
    q=casechange(s);
    printf("Manipulated string data:%s\n",s);
}
char* casechange(char *s)
{
    int i,j=strlen(s)-1,num;
    for(i=0;s[i];i++)
    {
        if(s[i]>='a'&&s[i]<='z')
        {
            s[i]-=32;
        }
        else if(s[i]>='A'&&s[i]<='Z')
        {
            s[i]+=32;
        }
    }
    if(s[i]>='0'&&s[i]<='9'&&s[j]>='0'&&s[j]<='9')
    //for(i=0;i<j;i++,j--)
    //{
    {
        num=s[i];
        s[i]=s[j];
        s[j]=num;
    }
    //}
    return s;
}
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: It's not as trivial as switching case. You could skip ahead to find the end of the number (until the first non-numerical char), mark that position, write it moving backwards, return to the mark

Comment: after executing it will only prints first string only and the rest of output vanishes

Comment: Have you verified that it is reading in the whole line?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with "after executing it will only prints first string only and the rest of output vanishes" is:

```
scanf("%s",s);
```

The scanf() '%s' format string tells scanf to read in a string, but only up to the first space.  Hence, if you enter:

```
 "Hello 12345 WoRlD"
```

The scanf("%s", s) will copy only "Hello" into 's'.

To fix this, change:

```
scanf("%s",s);
```

To this:

```
fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
```

However, fgets() may leave a unwanted '\n' at the end of the string.  The unwanted '\n' can be eliminated by inserting the following code after the fgets():

```
q=strchr(s,'\n');
if(q)
   *q = '\0';
```

Then the output will be:

```
"hELLO 12345 wOrLd"
```

---

SPOILER ALERT!

See my version ['casechange()'](http://www.mahonri.info/SO/23687334_how-to-reverse-the-integers-between-two-strings-with-changing-lower-to-upper-u.c), which will also reverse the number.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char* casechange(char *);

int main(){
    char s[30];

    printf("Enter string data:");
    scanf("%29[^\n]",s);//%s : separated by white space
    casechange(s);
    printf("Manipulated string data:%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}

char* casechange(char *s){
    int i;
    for(i=0;s[i];i++){
        if(islower(s[i]))
            s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
        else if(isupper(s[i]))
            s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
        else if(isdigit(s[i])){
            int j, n;
            char num[30];
            sscanf(&s[i], "%29[0123456789]%n", num, &n);
            for(j=0;j<n;++j)
                s[i+j] = num[n-j-1];
            i+=n-1;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

---

```
else if(isdigit(s[i])){
    int j, n;
    char num;
    sscanf(&s[i], "%*[0123456789]%n", &n);
    for(j=0;j<n/2;++j){
        num = s[i+j];
        s[i+j] = s[i+n-j-1];
        s[i+n-j-1] = num;
    }
    i+=n-1;
}
```